# Probabilities with repetition

Tags: probability

I have a problem in probabilities that give me a lot of reflexion. I have a customs between 2 country, only 10% of the cars are arrested by the police. 10 cars pass the customs, what is the probability that no cars will be arrested.

 I made this calculus $$P(A) = {(\frac{9}{10})}^{10} = 0.349...$$
I first thought it was true but then the question is : 10 cars pass the customs, what is the probability that one car will be arrested. I came with the same idea :
$$P(B) = {(\frac{9}{10})}^{9} * \frac{1}{10} = 0.04...$$
There i knew that something went wrong but i don't know what.

Comment: You have to choose which of the $10$ drivers of those cars will be the person who is arrested (assuming that this is random, which is doubtful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(B) is wrong.
$P(B)=P(X=1)$ such that $X~B(10, 0.1)$.
Then, the probablilty goes to $P(X=1)=_{10}C_1(\frac{1}{10})(\frac{9}{10})^9$.
That's value is $0.3874\cdots$